# Sorting vectors in c++ asc and desc order

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector, stl

I have class Player, and i have to make static method `void Player::sortPlayers( vector<Player> &players, bool (*c)(const Player&, const Player&))` and the method should contain only one line, in which you call the function sort with which you can arrange players ascending or descending with age, and than in main create two functions `bool ascending(const Player &p1, const Player&p2)` and
`bool descending(const Player &p1, const Player &p)`.
I have done this in class:

```
void Player::sortPlayers(vector<Player> &players, bool (*c)(const Player&, const Player&)) {
sort(players.begin(),players.end());
}
```

How can I start in main? I tried this but it wont work(for asc):

```
bool ascending(const Player &p1, const Player &p2) {
    Player::sortPlayers(p1,p2);
}
```

error message:
`Non-const lvalue reference to type 'vector<Player>' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'const Player'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) takes three args and the third one is a comparator. You can define your comparator to make `std::sort` suite your needs, as follows

```
void Player::sortPlayers(vector<Player> &players, bool (*c)(const Player&, const Player&)) {//define sortPlayers function
std::sort(players.begin(),players.end(), c);
}


bool ascending(const Player &p1, const Player &p2) {//define ascending function here
    return p1.age < p2.age;
}

bool descending(const Player &p1, const Player &p2) {//define descending function here
    return p1.age > p2.age;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Player> players = ....;//initialize the vector of players here
    Players::sortPlayers(players, ascending);//sort them in ascending order
    Players::sortPlayers(players, descending);//sort them in descending order

}
```

Comment: When i try to call Players::sortPlayers(players, ascending); or Players::sortPlayers(players, descending); , it doesn't show errors but it doesn't print anything

Comment: @amy1122 off course. because it sorts the vector elements. It doesn't display them.